# Better way to restrict object to certain attributes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Suppose I have an object:

```
obj =
  foo: 'foo'
  bar: 'bar'
  // ... and lots of other stuff ...
  // ... these values vary, and are not actually hard coded ...
```

I'd like to create a copy of that object which contains *only* a subset of its attributes.

```
obj2 =
  foo: obj.foo
  bar: obj.bar
  // *doesn't* copy any other attributes from `obj`
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this? Something like

```
obj2 = copyOnly obj, ['foo', 'bar']
```

I mean, sure, I could write `copyOnly` myself, but I'm looking for the idiomatic way to do this, not the home baked way. Is there such an idiom that you can recommend for this scenario?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't really a proper method to copy an object, like slice() would for arrays, so copying an object (and I assume it's an object even if the curlybraces are missing) with preset properties only is even less likely to be that simple, and you will have to "roll your own".

Comment: @adeneo It is indeed an object; I used coffeescript syntax which allows you to omit some curly braces, semicolons, commas, and parens via whitespace sensitivity.

Comment: @adeneo: see http://coffeescript.org/.

Comment: Didn't notice the coffeescript tag, and never really use it, but it doesn't really matter with regards to my previous comment..

Comment: You could use [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) if you don't mind pulling in Underscore.

Comment: @muistooshort ah, `_.pick` is exactly what I was looking for! I haven't used underscore before; I'll have to check it out.

Comment: You can also use [`_.mixin`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) to patch in your own extensions too. It is a handy library, there's also lodash which is an optimized version with the same interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't describe this as more idiomatic than writing your own, but `lodash` (next generation `underscore`) has a `pick` function

http://lodash.com/docs#pick
`Creates a shallow clone of object composed of the specified properties. Property names may be specified as individual arguments or as arrays of property names.`

It also has an `omit`.

```
__ = require 'lodash'
__.pick(obj,['foo','bar'])
```

But it is also easy to write the equivalent with lots of Coffee idioms

```
pick = (obj, keys, obj2={}) ->
  obj2[key] = value for own key, value of obj when key in keys
  obj2
```

Or if you prefer to loop on the keys

```
pick = (obj, keys, obj2={}) ->
  obj2[key] = obj[key] for key in keys when obj[key]?
  obj2
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a custom function that takes in the original object and the fields you want? `keysArray` would be an array of all the named Keys to copy over from the original object.

```
function cloneObjectSelectKeys(obj, keysArray) {
    var newObj = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
        newObj[keysArray[i]] = obj[keysArray[i]];
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Demo in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9nAwP/

And in CoffeeScript:

```
cloneObjectSelectKeys = (obj, keysArray) ->
    newObj = {}
    for key in keysArray
      newObj[key] = obj[key]
    newObj
```

Comment: tymeJV's answer is about as idiomatic as it gets. Noting that the idiomatic way to *clone* an object is just a function that loops through and copies own properties to a new object, you shouldn't be resistant to a function as a solution. This is just what the guts of JS libraries look like.

Comment: I was just hoping that a commonly used JS library would be suggested as the solution for this.

Comment: you mean, LIKE A CONSTRUCTOR!? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var obj = {
'property' : 'value',
'property_1' : 'value_1',
'property_2' : 'value_2'
};
function clone(srcObject, propertiesArray) {
    var objcopy = {};
    for(propperty in propertiesArray) {
        objcopy [propertiesArray[propperty]] = srcObject[propertiesArray[propperty]];
    }
    return objcopy;
}
var myClone = clone(obj, ['property', 'property_2']);
```